# Draw / display a route by GPS coordinates (GPX) with .Net Maui control "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"

Tags: maui

Is it possible to draw a route with the control "[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps/)" in .net Maui?

I have a GPX file that I would like to display on the map.

Example data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
  <trk>
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <desc>XYZ</desc>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="42.847881" lon="-80.467515">
        <ele>245.54</ele>
        <time>2020-03-27T12:15:00Z</time>
        <desc />
        <fix>none</fix>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="42.848728" lon="-80.43962">
        <ele>237.30</ele>
        <time>2020-03-27T12:25:00Z</time>
        <desc />
        <fix>none</fix>
      </trkpt>
      ...
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: I have not used it, but [Map / Polygons, Polylines, …](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0#polygons-polylines-and-circles) looks like what you need to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @ToolmakerSteve: you can use Polylines.

Microsoft documentation: [Create a polyline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-polyline)

Note: You need to *zoom in* on the map a lot to see the route. Even with a very high *StrokeWidth* used

**Example:**

```
// instantiate a polyline
Polyline polyline = new Polyline
{
    StrokeColor = Colors.Red,
    StrokeWidth = 8
};

foreach (var waypoint in waypoints)
{
    polyline.Geopath.Add(new Location(waypoint.Latitude, waypoint.Longitude));
}

// Add the Polyline to the map's MapElements collection
map.MapElements.Add(polyline);
```

Example to load GPX File: [Using Linq to XML with C# to Read Gpx Files](https://weblogs.asp.net/jimjackson/using-linq-to-xml-with-c-to-read-gpx-files)